# Wanted to store the Url in phpmyadmin coming back from Firebase storage when calling getdownloadUrl method

Tags: php, firebase, react-native

I want to store the whole Url of the image in my MySQL database coming from firebase storage when calling getDownloadUrl() method.

When doing the above I'm able to save the url but the token gets cut.

This is what I gets in my database

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/vibesproject-b54f0.appspot.com/o/UserProfileImages/Shaks?alt=media
```

and when alerting the same url in the app I got the whole path as shown in the below figure.

How can I store the whole path with the token in the database

This is the App image
[image]

Comment: Terminology note: Phpmyadmin isn't a database, it's just an administration tool. There are other similar tools available which do the same job. Your database itself is MySQL. Make sure you understand the different components of your setup and what their jobs are.

Comment: Anyway a picture of your app is not much use to us. We can't fix a picture. We need to see the code which sends the data to the server and tries to save it to the database. Maybe we also need to see the table definition. Somewhere it seems to be truncating the value. We can't tell you where without some relevant code etc.

Comment: Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` in phpMyAdmin and copy/paste the output to your question

Answer (score 1):

Check that the MySQL column length is not too short to store the whole URL.

Actually I would suggest using a column type of `TEXT` instead of `VARCHAR`.